# Java - Get all data from another class stored in a static List

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

This is the Dialog class where I add new person to a static List

```
public class DialogInput extends Dialog{
   public static List<Person> person = new LinkedList<Person>();

   Text txtName;    

   @Override
   protected Control createPartControl(Composite parent){
     ...
     txtName = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
   }

   @Override
   protected void okPressed(){
      Person p = new Person();
      p.setName(txtName.getText());
      person.add(p);
   }
}
```

// ANOTHER CLASS in a different file.

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart{
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent){

    // HOW TO GET LIST ?    

    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `DialogInput.person`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart{
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent){

    // HOW TO GET LIST ? 
    List<Person> personList = DialogInput.person;   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart{


    public void createPartControl(Composite parent){


       List<String> pList = DialogInput.person;
    }
}
```